# Nhibernate Query Select only those exist in the Child table at lease one

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I have a problem with my Nhibernate query.

My XML mapping

[image]

[image]

I have 2 table, TableA (KeyField1, Field2, Field3) and TableB (KeyField1, DateField)

```
TableA
------------------
KeyField1 | Field2  | Field 3
K1        | A1      | True
K2        | A2      | True
K3        | A3      | True
K4        | A4      | False





TableB
-------------------------------------------------------------
TableBID                             | KeyField1 | DateField
9CFA1E9F-7680-4715-BD5B-8DE674DB6EA6 | K1        | 12/17/2010
11C8226E-AEF2-4042-AADD-BDDBA35D83D6 | K3        | 12/17/2010
3971C949-673E-4FE5-B9B4-D73949F2FC53 | K3        | 12/21/2010
```

I would like to have result like this

```
TableA
------------------
KeyField1 | Field2  | Field 3
K1        | A1      | True
K3        | A3      | True
```

Means that I would like to have all records in TableA where at lease only one present in TableB.

I have try this way but not succeeded

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(TableA), "_request");
query.CreateAlias("TableB", "pl");
query.Add(
    Restrictions.And(    
        Restrictions.Eq("Field3", true),
        Restrictions.Gt( Projections.Count("pl.ID") , 0)
    )
);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Checked your profile and found that this should help you to understand SO: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

We can use subquery and EXISTS statement

```
TableA parent = null;
TableB child = null;

// parent query (TableA)
// will be filtered by existing children
// but still will be ready for paging
var parentQuery = session.QueryOver<TableA>(() => parent)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereExists(
        // subquery, where we assure that child exists for parent ID
        QueryOver.Of<TableB>(() => child)
            .Where(() => child.TableA.ID == parent.ID)
            .Select(_ => child.ID)
    );

// parents which fit to our needs
IList<TableA> result = parentQuery
    .Take(10)
    .Skip(0)
    .List<TableA>();
```

*That is `QueryOver` syntax and `ICriteria` would be almost the same...*

Comment: Dear Radim Köhler, Finnaly I found an answer by using query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Field3", true))
                             .Add(
                                    Subqueries.PropertyIn(
                                                        "ID", DetachedCriteria
                                                              .For<TableB>()
                                                              .SetProjection(Projections.Property("TableA.ID"))
                                                        )
                                  );

Comment: Great to see that my answer helped you